# Showing, hiding, and closing forms

Tags: c#, forms

I just want to know the code for showing,hiding, and exiting forms in C#.

Let's say for 3 forms named
Form1,
Form2,
Form3

I know in visual basic its easy to do these functions with the below codes. 
Visual Basic codes:

```
  Me.hide() --> Hides Form1
  Form2.show() --> Shows Form2
  Form3.close()  --> exits Form3
```

What's the C# equivalent to the above Visual Basic codes?

Comment: Your problem is with managing/tracking instances, not with using Forms. SHow a concrete piece of code.

Comment: And keep in mind that C# is case sensitive. `Close != close`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like this

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.Show();
```

You can also use `.ShowDialog();` this will make a form like a popup screen that you need to close to be able to use the rest of the program.

To close a form you can do

```
this.Close();
```

or

```
this.Hide();
```